# How can I remove a tapped event from a page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have added this code to the OnAppearing on a page.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        tap.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("HelpTab2");
        };
    }
```

The problem is that now the method seems to be adding more and more tapped commands.

Is there a way that I can remove this from the page when the page disappears?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer from Jason, if you have the view setup in xaml, you can subscribe to the tapped event there, and the view will handle the subscription for you you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can, but not with an anonymous delegate.  You have to use an actual event handler

```
// add handler
tap.Tapped += MyTappedHandler;

// remove handler
tap.Tapped -= MyTappedHandler;

protected void MyTappedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Shell.Current.GoToAsync("HelpTab2");
};
```